# Responsive Background Pictures for HTML

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I tried to adjust my background picture for phone screen, however, the background picture still not showing up correctly. I was planning to make it scale down but I am not sure why it still shows the height I want for the normal computer screen.

```css
@media (max-width: 375px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
    line-height: 34px;
  }
  #home h5 {
    font-size: 9px;
  }
#home {
  background: url('../images/home-bg.jpg') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The screen looks like this [Divrisk_Phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6t8u.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Add a closing `}` to your media query to see if that helps.